# address-based routing policy for Linux router?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, iptables

I have a home Linux router, it connects to the Internet through `ppp0`(both IPv4/v6), I run a wireguard VPN `wg0` on it. Its internal NIC interface is `lan0` (192.168.100.1/24, fd42:100::1/120), which connects to home network. I run a dnsmasq (192.168.100.1:53) as DHCP/DNS server.
I use these iptables rules to do NAT

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i lan0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

Now I want forward all the network traffic from the laptop (192.168.100.123, fd42:100::123) and android(192.168.100.124, fd42:100::124) to `wg0`, and other devices to `ppp0`, how to do that? Both ipv4/v6.

Additionally, I want redirect the 2 devices' DNS requests upon 192.168.100.1:53, to 192.168.100.1:5300, and others still go to 192.168.100.1:53. How to do that?

Even more, I want transparently redirect all DNS requests(udp and tcp port 53) of the 2 devices upon any DNS servers, to 192.168.100.1:5300, as some apps do DNS requests themselves. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want forward all the network traffic from the laptop (192.168.100.123, fd42:100::123) and android(192.168.100.124, fd42:100::124) to wg0, and other devices to ppp0, how to do that? Both ipv4/v6.

For both IPv4 and IPv6 – set up *policy routing* using `ip rule`.

1. Make sure you only have one default route, through ppp0.
2. Create a second routing table, with its own default route through wg0. If you're using wg-quick or systemd-networkd, they can do this for you using the `Table=` option:

   ```
   [Interface]
   Table = 42

   [Peer]
   # wg-quick will generate routes from all peers' AllowedIPs
   Endpoint = <your_server>
   AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
   ```

   Manually, it would be done like this (e.g. in PostUp):

   ```
   ip -4 route add default dev wg0 table 42
   ip -6 route add default dev wg0 table 42
   ```
3. Create a policy routing rule to select this table:

   ```
   ip -4 rule add pref 500 from 192.168.100.123/31 lookup 42
   ip -6 rule add pref 500 from fd42:100::123/128 lookup 42
   ```

(You can also create policy rules that match TCP/UDP ports or iptables/nft packet marks.)

Note: If you have multiple LAN subnets (with a bunch of local routes in the 'main' table), beware that the policy rule will override those as well – preventing the laptop from accessing other LAN subnets. To solve this you would need either to copy all routes into the new table, or a higher priority rule that does a lookup for everything *but* the default route:

```
ip -4 rule add pref 100 to 192.168.0.0/24 lookup main
-or-
ip -4 rule add pref 100 lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
```

---

> Additionally, I want redirect the 2 devices' DNS requests upon 192.168.100.1:53, to 192.168.100.1:5300, and others still go to 192.168.100.1:53. How to do that?

Create an iptables or nft DNAT rule (much like "port forwarding" rules documented elsewhere). If the redirection is done to the same system that the rule is on, you can also use an iptables REDIRECT rule which does the same thing.

```
chain prerouting {
    ip saddr {192.168.100.123, 192.168.100.124} ip daddr 192.168.100.1 jump {
        tcp dport 53 dnat to 192.168.100.1:5300
        udp dport 53 dnat to 192.168.100.1:5300
    }
    # Repeat with: ip6 saddr ... ip6 daddr ...
}
```

iptables:

```
-s 192.168.100.123 -d 192.168.100.1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT ...
-s 192.168.100.123 -d 192.168.100.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT ...
```

(You need rules for TCP 53 **and** UDP 53, as DNS uses both.)

> Even more, I want transparently redirect all DNS requests(udp and tcp port 53) of the 2 devices upon any DNS servers, to 192.168.100.1:5300, as some apps do DNS requests themselves. How to do that?

Same as above, but leave out the "destination IP" from the rule (i.e. no `-d` or `ip daddr`).

However, don't forget to add equivalent rules for IPv6 as well – `ip6 saddr` match for nftables, or the completely separate `ip6tables` command for iptables.

Comment: I use these iptables rules to do NAT, should I modify them?

Comment: # iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A FORWARD -i lan0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu

Comment: There's only one NAT rule there and it's for SNAT, it has nothing to do with DNAT here.